# How to re-use the fuzzy-matching (for address) code built with apply/sapply, in a data.frame's groupby setup i.e. match within groups?

Tags: r, dplyr, sapply

I'm trying to group a list of addresses for a bunch of individuals—an individual can have more than 1 address mapped to him—while addresses are captured in the system with all manual inconsistencies e.g. typo (or) additional info/title in some versions of same address.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  individuals = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
  addresses = c(
    'king st toronto',
    'queen st',
    'king toronto',
    'broadway st',
    'broadway ave',
    'attn: broadway ave'
  )
)
```

It doesn't matter which one of an address' variation I'm choosing finally, but all that is required is, group/recognize them as ONE same address, say, in a new column.

I used Levenshtein edit distance, along with baseR's  apply and sapply as shown below to do fuzzy matching, and then map to 1 unique address(in fuzzy sense) per individual (here I picked the variation with fewer characters but any one representation is okay).

```
matches <-
  sapply(df[['addresses']], function(pattern)
    agrepl(pattern, df[['addresses']], max.distance = 0.3))

apply(matches , 1, function(arg)
  df[['addresses']][arg][which.min(nchar(df[['addresses']][arg]))])
```

This code works as stand-alone for 1 group, but I'm not able to generalize it to entire data.frame with multiple groups, say in a dplyr/groupby setup. I tried using plyr:ddply(data.frame, .(groupby_var), `<FUNCTION>`) but ran into error 'Error in apply() dim(X) must have a positive length'.

Expected Output:

| individuals | addresses |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | **king toronto** |
| 1 | queen st |
| 1 | king toronto |
| 1 | broadway st |
| 2 | broadway ave |
| 2 | **broadway ave** |

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option that might help you out; I create a new column of all addresses that match the address given within a certain distance by pasting together the similar addresses. If you only want one address then you can subset the string up to the comma-space separator. Then you can group by the combined name and do your normal `tidyverse` functions on each group of addresses, or group by individual and paste together all the possible addresses for them.

Interestingly, the Levenshtein edit distance is non-symmetrical so you may run into problems with it. For example, "attn: broadway ave" is within 0.3 of "broadway st" but "broadway st" is NOT within 0.3 of "attn: broadway ave". I bumped up your distance to 0.5 in the example below but you'll likely run into this problem elsewhere.

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(agrep_matches=list(agrep(addresses, df$addresses, max.distance = 0.5))) %>%
  mutate(other_names=paste(df$addresses[unlist(agrep_matches)], collapse = ", "))
```

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Rowwise: 
  individuals addresses          agrep_matches other_names                                  
        <dbl> <chr>              <list>        <chr>                                        
1           1 king st toronto    <int [2]>     king st toronto, king toronto                
2           1 queen st           <int [1]>     queen st                                     
3           1 king toronto       <int [2]>     king st toronto, king toronto                
4           1 broadway st        <int [3]>     broadway st, broadway ave, attn: broadway ave
5           2 broadway ave       <int [3]>     broadway st, broadway ave, attn: broadway ave
6           2 attn: broadway ave <int [3]>     broadway st, broadway ave, attn: broadway ave
```

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely a step closer to the solution; now is there a way to restrict grouping (fuzzy matching) to an individual alone at a time e.g. 'broadway st' and 'broadway ave' of  1 and 2, respectively, are to be left as such, and no fuzzy-matching is to be done across the individuals/groups.